# For the_content() Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have a post in category and i use `the_content()` in my loop. After, the result output : Follower ( with any posts ), only I use echo `get_the_content(`) when the content to display. Why `the_content()` is not working?

please illuminate...

This is code

```
    <div id="ani-content">
     <?php 
        $gallery = new WP_Query('post_type=gallery');
        while($gallery -> have_posts()) : $gallery -> the_post();
     ?>
     <div class="wrap-frame">
         <div class="frame">
             <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
             <div class="image">
               <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail('p_images_gallery'); }?>
             </div>
             <div class="p_content">
                <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
             </div>
             <div class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Readmore</a></div>
         </div>
     </div>
    <?php endwhile;wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: You mean <?php the_content(); ?> does not work for you or did you use it like <?php echo the_content(); ?>

Comment: Show the code that isn't working, and define what you mean by "not working" (i.e. describe both what you want and what you're actually getting").